# A closed expression for this sequence of integers

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Say we have $a_k=n-p$ for $n,p \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ where $n-p >0$ and $a_1=n-p-1$, and in general:

$a_k=n-p$

$a_1=n-p-1$

$a_{k-1}=n-p-2$

$a_2=n-p-3$

$a_{k-2}=n-p-4$

$a_{3}=n-p-5$

$\vdots$

and so on. The idea is that if the sequence $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ is ordered from greatest to smallest, we have $(a_k,a_1,a_{k-1},a_{2},a_{k-2},a_3,...)$ where all the numbers are consecutive.

I want to find a general closed expression for $a_i$ for $i\in\{1,...,k\}$, but I cannot seem to find a way to come up with it.

Comment: Yes, I typed $a_k$ correctly. See the edit.

Comment: For a given $k$, what about something like $a_j=2j-k+\max(0, 2k+1-4j)$?

Comment: @user3733558 Seems like an interesting, if incomplete idea.  Unclear if it is incomplete.  If it is, unclear if you intend that to provoke the OP's thinking.  Assuming that you want to provide a complete answer, then with respect to any given value $k$, for which values of $j$ would your formula for $a_j$ pertain?

Comment: @user2661923 the idea was to offer an idea for a possible solution, and indeed leave details out for the OP to figure out by him/her-self. Either that or use this idea as a conversation starter for clarifying what the OP was after, in case it happened that this particular idea wouldn't match some not yet mentioned requirements. The OP kept silent though, so... To answer your other question, I was assuming $j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$.

Comment: @user3733558 I thought that it might be something like that, which is why my comment began "Unclear *this*..." and "Unclear *that* ...".

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to split the problem into two cases with even and odd $k$. Here we consider the case $k=2K$ even:
\begin{align*}
\left(a_j\right)_{1\leq j\leq 2K}=\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,\color{blue}{a_K,a_{K+1}},\ldots,a_{2K}\right)
\end{align*}

We list the elements $a_j, 1\leq j\leq k=2K$ in a detailed way to better see what's going on. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ll}
\qquad a_{2K}\ \ \ =a_k\quad=n-p&\qquad\qquad\; a_1=n-p-1\\
\qquad a_{2K-1}=a_{k-1}=n-p-2&\qquad\qquad\; a_2=n-p-3\\
\qquad a_{2K-2}=a_{k-2}=n-p-4&\qquad\qquad\; a_3=n-p-5\\
\qquad\quad\quad\ \ \  \vdots\qquad&\qquad\qquad \quad\ \ \;\vdots\\
a_{2K-(K+1)}=a_{k-(K-1)}=n-p-2(K-1)&\qquad\qquad a_K=n-p-(2K-1)\\
\qquad\qquad\ =a_{K+1}\quad\ \ =n-p-2K+2&\qquad\qquad \quad\  = n-p-2K+1
\end{array}
\end{align*}

> From the list above we obtain for $\left(a_j\right)_{1\leq j\leq k}=\left(a_j\right)_{1\leq j\leq 2K}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_j}&=
> \begin{cases}
> n-p-2j+1&\qquad\quad\ \ \ \;1\leq j\leq K\\
> n-p-2K+2(j-K)&\qquad K+1\leq j\leq 2K
> \end{cases}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=
> \begin{cases}
> n-p-2j+1&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1\leq j\leq K\\
> n-p-4K+2j&\qquad\qquad\quad K+1\leq j\leq 2K
> \end{cases}}
> \end{align*}

The odd case can be obtained similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I thought it would be helpful to find a closed form for $\min(x,y)$. This is not so difficult to guess. It is:

$$\min(x,y) = \frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}$$

which you can verify in each case.

Then, your sequence is described by:

$$a_j = n-p-q$$

where $q = 2\min\bigg((k-j), (j-\frac{1}{2})\bigg)$.

Using the formula above, we derive the closed form:

$$a_j = n-p- \Bigg(k-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\big|2k-4j+1\big|}{2}\Bigg).$$